# Flutter ScreenSharing or FileSharing in VideoCall

Tags: flutter

I'm using agora AS Video Call package in flutter.

I need to add *ScreenSharing* or *FileSharing* functionalities to the Video call, so the user in the VideoCall can *Show The File*, or *Show the File* and *Throw the Screen Sharing* on his mobile, but agora supports *ScreenSharing* only in Native, not in flutter.

Can someone help please.